# Нюансы проектирования REST-архитектуры

Tags: архитектура, rest

Есть некоторая сущность, которая представляет собой узел графа и хранится в обычной реляционной базе данных. "Наружу" сущность смотрит как REST-ресурс с подресурсами, в том числе со связями:

```
/entity
/entity/:uuid
/entity/:uuid/parent
/entity/:uuid/parent/:uuid
```

При реализации этого интерфейса появилось несколько вопросов:

1. Как должен правильно выглядеть метод на получение сразу нескольких сущностей? `/entity?ids=%uuid%,%uuid%,%uuid%` меня немного смущает из-за того, что для отдельной единичной сущности существует отдельный ресурс.
2. Будет ли считаться нарушением архитектуры, если методы обновления связей (POST/PUT) будут принимать список идентификаторов, а метод получения (GET) будет возвращать готовые сущности?
3. Будет ли считаться нарушением архитектуры возврат простой строки? Никогда такого не встречал, и, насколько помню, спека JSON требует в качестве корневой сущности либо массив, либо объект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вполне нормальное решение: `/entity` - коллекция, `/entity?ids=%uuid%,%uuid%,%uuid%` - коллекция с фильтром. И вообще [все так делают](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids).

   Теоретически, проблема может возникнуть, если вы запросите очень много uuid-ов. Они сами по себе довольно длинные. Протокол HTTP [не накладывает](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1) ограничений на длину GET-запроса. Но веб-сервера и прокси могут такие ограничения иметь.
2. Не совсем ясно, что вы хотите сделать. Если речь о том, чтобы обновить `PUT`-ом состояния ресурсов через URL вида `/entity?ids=%uuid%,%uuid%,%uuid%`, то почему бы и нет. Но тогда они все станут одинаковыми по своему содержимому. Если `id` является частью передаваемого содержимого - будут сложности. Массовый `PATCH`, выглядит логичнее.

   Можно еще рассмотреть массовое создание `POST`-ом. Что-то вроде

   ```
   POST /entity?batch=true

   //содержимое новых ресурсов
   ```

   а в ответ возвращать групповой URL на созданные ресурсы в заголовке

   ```
   HTTP/1.0 201 Created
   Location: /entity?ids=%uuid%,%uuid%,%uuid%
   ```
3. Нет, не будет. Ресурс не обязан быть именно JSON-ом. Можно возвращать хоть черта в ступе, упомянув в `Content-Type` что-нибудь вроде `application/vnd.devil-in-mortar`. Другое дело, если весь ваш REST - это API, опирающийся на JSON. Тут выйдет несколько неконсистентно, но и не смертельно: просто укажите `Content-Type: text/plain` и опишите это в документации. Просто пользователям, привыкшим к динамически генерируемым проксям и маппингам JSON ↔ DTO, придется обратить на этот вызов чуть больше внимания.

Comment: По 2 - предполагается, что я делаю `PUT /entity/:id/child \r\n\r\n [1, 2, 3]`, а в ответ сервак мне возвращает не такой же массив, а целиковые сущности дочерних узлов. По 3 - хотелось бы везде иметь JSON, но формально, насколько понимаю,  ответ `"de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014"` JSON-ом не является ("[*A JSON text is a serialized object or array*](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)"), и тут могут возникнуть проблемы вроде описанных проблем с длиной request uri.